# RequiredFieldValidator keeps refreshing the page

Tags: asp.net, requiredfieldvalidator

I am creating a register form and when the user clicks on the confirm password field, the page refreshes and I lose the text from the other field (the password field)

The code to the confirm password is here below:

```
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ValidationGroup="CreateAccount1" 
    CssClass="FieldValidator" EnableClientScript="true"
    ControlToValidate="TxtPass" ID="pPassword" runat="server"
    Text="Password required" ErrorMessage="Password required" />
```

Thanks,
C.

Comment: The given code is exactly correct, no issue there, issue may be in the confirm password text box. please provide the code there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the [AutoPostBack](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.textbox.autopostback.aspx) property of your first password field is set to `true`. In that case, the page will be posted back to the server as soon as that field loses focus, bypassing client validation.

You might want to set that property to `false` instead.